# MySQL 5.5.57 Database Design suggestions request for 'user' table in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to make a `user` table in an education database where a user can have the following profiles:

```
1. Admin
2. School Admin
3. Tutor
4. Student
5. Parent
6. School Teacher
```

Now, the question is weather to make separate tables for each profile and use a key in the user to table to link with profile table or keep all in one and add a profile key to identify the type of user. Everyday new users are added in the database so its a growing database.

The queries which are run to fetch the data are specific to the profile. For example, the data will be fetched for one profile at a time. But, what about the cases where we need to get all the teachers of a student or all students of a teacher? In that case I will have to store the id of the student in the tutor and teacher table. What is the optimized way of going about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to make separate tables for profile and use a key in the user to table to link with profile table (if profiles are pre-configured)

if profiles are dynamic then you have to take care in your application like check profile exists or not, if not exists then first insert into profile table and then insert into user table. This may affect INSERT performance.

to get all the teachers of a student or all students of a teacher, you have to use self-join

Comment: The profiles are predefined. Only some of the profiles have profile specific columns so can I do the segregation only to the profiles which contain different set of columns? Basically, separate tables for some profiles and rest in the same user table

Comment: It wont be stable. In this case better include in user table itself. If the profile have different attribute then surely you should separate the profile and use key into user table.

Comment: The thing is that having separate tables for each one of them makes the design more flexible but might increase the joins too. Another reason for making separate tables is that the user table is growing. Everyday new users are added making the table bigger and bigger. If I see 10 years down the line then this design will fail as the no. of users will be huge.

Comment: There will be bridge tables as well, so looking for teachers of a student or students of a tutor can be fetched from the bridge tables as its a m-n relation.

Comment: if we separate it then it will be flexible and save memory but you said some profiles are user specific in this case you can't avoid to include the profile in user table. I always prefer the separate table only. If you can handle the FK properly in your application then you can separate the profile table or maintain bridge table.

Comment: Yeah, and separate tables is much cleaner too. Later, it will help in analysis as well. I mainly need separate tables for `Tutor, School Teacher, Student`. Making separate tables for others will not be much of an overhead as the other profiles are hardly queried. So, I guess making separate tables will be better.

Comment: I said some profiles have profile specific columns but others might not. Still, I think separate tables would be better because the other profiles apart from the three mentioned in the previous comment are hardly queried.

Comment: separate table will be good. Also ensure profile and user are one-to-one mapping. If user and profile are many-to-one then you should opt 3 table like profile, user and user_profile. eg. faculty can be a student for another course, In this case only one user but different role so you should manage with bridge table ( i mean 3 tables)

Comment: Yeah I understood what you are trying to say. One user can have only one type of profile so it will be one-to-one only. Thanks. Cheers!